# Why do I get bad request from python call to swagger APi?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a swagger api running in docker. I can call it thus:

```
  curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/my_api/1.0.0/my_route" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  
"Content-Type: application/json" 
-d "{\"places\":[{\"place_data\":{\"position\":[0.87073,0.4401963],\"sub\":
[0,0]},\"place_name\":\"place1\"},...,
\"streets\":[{\"street_data\":{\"position\":[0.456,0.568],\"sub\":[0,0]},\"street_name\":\"street_1\"}]}"
```

I try to call it from python:

```
json_string= """
    {"places":[{"place_data":{"position":[0.87073,0.4401963],"sub":
[0,0]},"place_name":"place1"},…,"streets":[{"street_data":{"position":[0.456,0.568],
"sub":[0,0]},"street_name":"street_1"}]}"""


url = 'http://localhost:8080/my_api/1.0.0/my_route'
headers = {'accept': 'text/plain', 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
res = requests.post(url, json=json_string, headers=headers)
```

but get:

```
b'{\n  "detail": "\'\\\\n{\\"places\\":[{\\"place_data…n    \' is not of type \'object\'",\n  "status": 400,
\n  "title": "Bad Request",\n  "type": "about:blank"\n}\n'
```

Is it to do with the `b` in front? (I have also tried setting `accept` to `application/json`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

`res = requests.post(url, data=json_string, headers=headers)`

ie `data=` instead of `json=`.